Cannot connect to Google sign in on my website
I am trying to implement a Google sign in option on my website by following their guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.

I created the credentials
I put the Google Platform Library code at the end of my head tags
I put the App's client ID  right after it and changed it to the client id I got from point 1.
I put a test button on the site as they provided <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

However when I now load the browser I get the following errors in the console (I replaced my domain and client ID from the errors with placeholders):
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/_/mss/boq-identity/_/js/k=boq-identity.IdpIFrameHttp.sv.IwDkfwbeEEg.es5.O/am=DAY/d=1/rs=AOaEmlEdZyiJuV_FbDciB-VB31grkH9-LA/m=base' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:115  Uncaught {error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://recensi…egister this origin for your project's client ID."}details: "Not a valid origin for the client: https://mywebsite.com has not been registered for client ID xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"[[Prototype]]: Object
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:115
setTimeout
_.nh @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:115
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:155
Wj @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:146
Promise.then
gk @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:148
_.ik @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:148
Ak @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:154
jk @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:153
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:148
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:252
xu.dispatchEvent @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:167
_.yv.Nr @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:206
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:199
_.g.iea @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:191
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:194
iframe:1 
    
    
POST https://accounts.google.com/_/IdpIFrameHttp/cspreport/fine-allowlist 400 (Bad Request)

What I tried
I tried to update my htaccess with something like the following but I still got the same error messages:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Security-Policy "
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://www.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data:;
    connect-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com;
    frame-src 'self' https://accounts.google.com https://www.gstatic.com;
    object-src 'none';
"
</IfModule>

I also tried added Authorized JavaScript origins for my stage website (which is live on the internet) but no change here either.
Questions
Can anyone please let me know how to fix this? Do the server providor need to change anything or am I missing something?

So your .htaccess contained this configuration to set the Content-Security-Policy before already, and you only added the https://www.gstatic.com origin?

@C3roe no it just contained the normal Wordpress stuff, I found some info on this online and tried to put it in there.

But apparently your site had a CSP set before already, the error message said, "because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ..." - so go figure out where that was actually set, and add your modification there.

@C3roe, It is a clean wordpress installation with no plugins. Could it be the server providors setting it somewhere? I don't see any other htaccess file than straight under public_html

My guess would be that this was set on the web server configuration level. If you have access to any hosting config UI like plesk, cpanel, etc., go check in there; otherwise, talk to your hoster.

@C3roe They only run Direct Admin, I will see if it is possible to change my VPS settings there or otherwise contact them. Thanks for the help!

Should be possible, according to https://wiredbyteit.com/web-design/direct-admin/content-security-policies-in-directadmin-best-implementation-practices/#:~:text=To%20configure%20Content%20Security%20Policies%20in%20DirectAdmin%2C%20follow%20these%20step%2Dby%2Dstep%20instructions.
